# Problems with the htaccess in yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2, multisite

I'm trying to do something in the htaccess and it does not work out. I have a multi-shop project in yii2 that has several themes that are loaded according to the domain from which it is accessed. The project is organized as follows:

```
-project
   -framework
      -themes
         -views_default
         -views1
         -views2
   -.htaccess (file that I want to modify)
```

In the htaccess I want to put the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/framework/themes/views_default
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) framework/themes/views_default/$1
```

My intention with this rule is that when a file is loaded from any theme (other than "views_default"), and that file does not exist, then it has to go to load it from the "views_default" theme in which that file will be.
Unfortunately my rule does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: does your htaccess in project directory?

Comment: Yes, it is inside, together with framework.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` it matches full root path so, change it to `%{REQUEST_URI}`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/framework/themes/views_default
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /framework/themes/views_default/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it does not work. He removed the header.php from the "view1" theme and when loading the web I should have taken the header.php from the "views_default" theme but he says he can not find it. Error: The view file does not exist: C: \ wamp64 \ www \ myproject \ project \ framework \ themes \ views1 \ views \ common \ _header.php

Comment: change this line RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /framework/themes/views_default/$1 [L,R=301] with this  RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %DOCUMENT_ROOT}/framework/themes/views_default/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: It does not work for me, it keeps saying the same thing, it does not find in the file header.php.